# How to keep the dropdown menu open/active on many pages with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way so that when i'm in a particular link for example `www.website.com/bienetre.html,` the website looks at the links and when he finds the link in my menu, the dropdown menu should be open so that the user doesn't have to open all the dropdowns to find the next link.

I have been trying to do the following on javascript. Whenever i load the page, the website compares the actual link on the navigation bar to the links on the menu. Whenever he finds the link he opens the dropdown menu and activate a class on the link in the menu.

```js
/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i].getAttribute("href");
  var url = location.href;
  var $dropdownmenu = $(this);
  console.log(link);
  if (link === url) {
    console.log(link);
    //console.log( $dropdownmenu ); // this is your dropdown menu which you want to display
    //console.log($($dropdownmenu).parents('div'));

  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="subNavLeft" class="mainNav2017sub desktop">
    <div class="subNavCol">
      <div id="headerSub1">ORIENTATION</div>

      <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn"> Bien être et counseling</button>

      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p><a href="bienetre.html">Bienêtre et santé mentale</a></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p><a href="vie-spirituelle.html">Vie spirituelle</a></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="dropdown-btn"> Orientation</button>

      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p><a href="respect-en-milieu-detude.html">Respect en milieu d'étude</a></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p><a href="orientation.html">Service d'orientation pédagogique</a></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p><a href="droits-et-recours.html">Droits et recours des étudiants</a></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p><a href="prets">Prêts aux étudiants</a></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p><a href="emploietudiant.html">Emplois pour étudiants</a></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <p><a href="annuaire.html">Détails sur l'admission, les exigences et les règlements</a></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would console.log(url, link) see if it makes sense to compare them without normalizing first

Comment: @isherwood thank you for your help, i tried to be as clear as i can!

Comment: @zylo I hope that helps making the problem more understandable!

Comment: The convenient Tidy button in the snippet editor will fix that wall of code. Code should _always_ be properly formatted.

Comment: `links[i].closest('.dropdown-container').classList.add("active")`